# Solr SSl self sign certificate

Tags: ssl, redirect, https, solr

I have a problem with solr 8_4 SSL.
I can't connect with `https://localhost:8983` ,but `http://localhost:8983` is worked.
I am use https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/enabling-ssl.html for configuring SSL with self sign certificate.

Setting made are :

```
SOLR_SSL_ENABLED=true 
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=/opt/solr/server/etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=secret SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=/opt/solr/server/etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=secret 
SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=false 
SOLR_SSL_WANT_CLIENT_AUTH=false 
SOLR_SSL_CLIENT_HOSTNAME_VERIFICATION=false 
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE=JKS 
SOLR_SSL_CHECK_PEER_NAME=true
```

Comment: did you Move key store and certificate to Solr?

Comment: To enable SSL, edit the file C:\Program Files\solr-6.6.2\bin\solr.in.cmd. Uncomment properties starting with Solr_SSL_*:

Comment: After all the setting did you restart the solr?

Comment: os version centos 8   I edited solr.in.sh

Comment: SOLR_SSL_ENABLED=true
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=/opt/solr/server/etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=/opt/solr/server/etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=false
SOLR_SSL_WANT_CLIENT_AUTH=false
SOLR_SSL_CLIENT_HOSTNAME_VERIFICATION=false
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE=JKS
SOLR_SSL_CHECK_PEER_NAME=true

Comment: yes i restarted centos and solr

Comment: Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  C5:CE:4D:BE:2D:5B:C7:8C:88:E6:78:FE:04:2E:4B:29
         SHA1: 18:4D:FD:4C:36:9E:A8:88:7B:CB:74:03:32:0C:18:EC:FD:1E:9A:EB
         SHA256: 2F:75:16:6D:66:23:5C:9F:B8:66:23:F2:EB:EB:10:70:23:EE:07:20:2B:92:B6:23:7F:CC:8F:A1:72:95:ED:62
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: sapsolrtemp2
  IPAddress: 192.168.20

Comment: did you copy the generated certificate and keystore files (solr-ssl.keystore.jks, solr-ssl.keystore.p12) to ..\solr-6.6.2\server\etc\.

Comment: yes of course :)

Comment: the last check is did you import the certificate?

Comment: Chrome return :This site can’t provide a secure connection192.168.202.38 sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/err_ssl_protocol_error/  ....another one is https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/fix-err-ssl-protocol-error/

Comment: I tried it isn't help because http working if it is chrome problem it cant work on http